# Invalid argument supplied for foreach(); Array not being set properly

Tags: php, arrays, class

Here is my code:

```
class Subscriber extends DatabaseObject {

    protected static $table_name = "email_list";
    protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'email');

    public $id;
    public $email;

    function __construct() {
        self::$object = new Subscriber;
    }
}
```

In the parent class, `DatabaseObject`, is the problem:

```
class DatabaseObject {

    protected static $object;
    protected static $db_fields;

    protected function attributes() {
    $attributes = array();
    foreach (self::$db_fields as $field) {
        // edited
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

However, I get `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` because of the line:

`foreach (self::$db_fields as $field) {`

Why isn't the array being set?  I tried setting it in the `constructor` manually but it did not work either.

Comment: Looking at your code, `$db_fields` does not look like an array. `foreach` expects an array as it's first argument. Please review the `foreach` documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: Late Static Binding: `foreach (static::$db_fields as $field) {`
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method in `DatabaseObject` will access the `$db_fields` property from `DatabaseObject` rather than from `Subscriber` unless you use [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) via the `static` keyword rather than `self`

```
foreach (static::$db_fields as $field) {
```

requires PHP >= 5.3.0

Comment: Learn something new everyday. +1

Comment: perfect; thanks.  I've always wanted to know how that works.  didn't realize this was an instance of it.